# Box content sdk throw exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, box

I am trying to integrate `Box Content SDK` in my android project, but unfortunately I have got the exception and which I have mentioned here with full `logcat`. I have also mentioned the code line and that function which gives me an exception.

Kindly help me if anyone has an idea on this.

Thank you in advanced!!

**Logcat Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } in com.box.androidsdk.content.auth.OAuthActivity$1@536d7ca0
                at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.box.androidsdk.content.auth.OAuthActivity$1.onReceive(OAuthActivity.java:93)
                at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Reference code line of OAuthActivity 93:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnectedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) && SdkUtils.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
                // if we are not showing a web page then redo the authentication.
                if (!oauthView.getUrl().startsWith("http")){
                    startOAuth();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```